# Asking a Generic Method to Throw Specific Exception Type on FAIL

Tags: c#, generics, exception

Right, I know I am totally going to look an idiot with this one, but my brain is just *not* kicking in to gear this morning.

I want to have a method where I can say "if it goes bad, come back with this type of Exception", right?

For example, something like (**and this doesn't work**):

```
    static ExType TestException<ExType>(string message) where ExType:Exception
    {
        Exception ex1 = new Exception();
        ExType ex = new Exception(message);
        return ex;
    }
```

Now whats confusing me is that we *KNOW* that the generic type is going to be of an Exception type due to the *where* clause. However, the code fails because we cannot implicitly cast *Exception* to *ExType*. We cannot explicitly convert it either, such as:

```
    static ExType TestException<ExType>(string message) where ExType:Exception
    {
        Exception ex1 = new Exception();
        ExType ex = (ExType)(new Exception(message));
        return ex;
    }
```

As that fails too.. So **is this kind of thing possible?** I have a strong feeling its going to be real simple, but I am having a tough day with the old noggin, so cut me some slack :P

---

### Update

Thanks for the responses guys, looks like it wasn't me being a *complete* idiot! ;)

OK, so [Vegard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397/asking-a-generic-method-to-throw-specific-exception-type-on-fail#41398) and [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397/asking-a-generic-method-to-throw-specific-exception-type-on-fail#41404) got me on to the point where I could instantiate the correct type, but then obviously got stuck because the *message* param is read-only following instantiation.

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397/asking-a-generic-method-to-throw-specific-exception-type-on-fail#41408) hit the nail right on the head with his response, I have tested this and all works fine. Here is the example code:

```
    static ExType TestException<ExType>(string message) where ExType:Exception, new ()
    {
        ExType ex = (ExType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ExType), message);
        return ex;
    }
```

Sweet! :)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Frankly, I think that writing a method in such a way ("if it goes bad, come back with this type of Exception") might prove to be too problematical wrt edge cases (see my comments below re. exception types where `message` is *not* the first string arg) and also wrt (in)flexibility.  Re. the latter, you might want to set more than the exception's message, or use some values/variables that only held by the caller.  Perhaps an `Action` delegate that can be called back to throw the exception might be more appropriate in many cases?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can almost do it like this:

```
static void TestException<E>(string message) where E : Exception, new()
{
    var e = new E();
    e.Message = message;
    throw e;
}
```

However, that doesn't compile because Exception.Message is read only. It can only be assigned by passing it to the constructor, and there's no way to constrain a generic type with something other than a default constructor.

I think you'd have to use reflection (Activator.CreateInstance) to "new up" the custom exception type with the message parameter, like this:

```
static void TestException<E>(string message) where E : Exception
{
    throw Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(E), message) as E;
}
```

**Edit** Oops just realised you're wanting to *return* the exception, not throw it. The same principle applies, so I'll leave my answer as-is with the throw statements.

Comment: This assumes that the exception type has a constructor overload with signature `public ExceptionType (string message);`.  This is usually, but not always the case.  An exception is `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  Its constructors' first string argument is `paramName` not `message`.  Which is annoying.

Comment: `System.ArgumentNullException` also has constructor `public ArgumentNullException (string paramName);`

Answer (score 11):

The only issue with the solution is that it is possible to create a subclass of Exception which does not implement a constructor with a single string parameter, so the MethodMissingException might be thrown.

```
static void TestException<E>(string message) where E : Exception, new()
{
    try 
    {
      return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(E), message) as E;
    } 
    catch(MissingMethodException ex) 
    {
      return new E();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been instantiating inline the type of exception I want to throw, like this:

```
if (ItemNameIsValid(ItemName, out errorMessage))
    throw new KeyNotFoundException("Invalid name '" + ItemName + "': " + errorMessage);
if (null == MyArgument)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("MyArgument is null");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, instead:

```
static T TestException<Exception>(string message)
{}
```

because I have a feeling that putting in the generic constraint is not necessary as all throwable exceptions *must* inherit from System.Exception anyway.

Remember that generics do accept inherited types.

Answer (score -1):

I think seeing as all exceptions should have a parameterless constructor, and have the `Message` property, so the following should work:

```
static ExType TestException<ExType>(string message) where ExType:Exception
{
    ExType ex = new ExType();
    ex.Message = message;
    return ex;
}
```

Edit: OK, Message is read only, so you'll have to hope the class implements the Exception(string) constructor instead.

```
static ExType TestException<ExType>(string message) where ExType:Exception
{
    return new ExType(message);
}
```

Comment: Your second code snippet also doesn't compile. There is no way to specify a generic type constraint that expects one string argument for the constructor.